# PHP Session Start Bug

Tags: javascript, php

When i try a fetch post request to a file the echo isnt done, and I dont know why.

**/global/config.php**

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();

// SMTP
const SMTP_HOST = '(something)';
const SMTP_USER = '(something)';
const SMTP_USERNAME = '(something)';
const SMTP_PSW = '(something)';

// LINKS
define('DOC_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
const LINK_HOME = '/';
const IMPORT_PATH = DOC_ROOT . LINK_HOME;
const LINK_API = LINK_HOME . 'api/';
define('LINK_WEBSITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . LINK_HOME);

const APP_NAME = '(something)';
const LOGO = LINK_HOME . '(something)';
const LOGO_WHITE = LINK_HOME . '(something)';
const LOGO_SM = LINK_HOME . '(something)';
const LOGO_SM_WHITE = LINK_HOME . '(something)';
const DEFAULT_AVATAR = LINK_HOME . '(something)';

$page_name = '(Sem nome)';
require_once(IMPORT_PATH . "api/check.php");
```

**/api/check.php**

```php
$cur_loc = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (!str_contains($cur_loc, LINK_HOME . "api/auth/")) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) && !str_contains($cur_loc, LINK_HOME . "pages/auth/")) {
        header('Location: ' . LINK_HOME . 'pages/auth/login');
        exit();
    } else if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $cur_loc !== LINK_HOME . "pages/auth/logout" && str_contains($cur_loc, LINK_HOME . "pages/auth/")) {
        header('Location: ' . LINK_HOME);
        exit();
    }
}
```

**/api/user/edit.php**

```php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/global/config.php');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$response = ["status" => "error", "message" => "Método inválido!"];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {}
session_write_close();
echo json_encode($response, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

The script I'm using is this

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const form = document.querySelector("form#account-profile-details-form");
    const btnSubmit = document.querySelector("#account-info-submit");
    const validator = FormValidation.formValidation(form, {
        fields: {
            'email': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'E-mail é obrigatório'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'E-mail inválido'
                    },
                    invalidEmail: {
                        message: 'E-mail inválido'
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        plugins: {
            trigger: new FormValidation.plugins.Trigger(),
            bootstrap: new FormValidation.plugins.Bootstrap5({
                rowSelector: '.fv-row',
                eleInvalidClass: '',
                eleValidClass: ''
            })
        }
    });

    form.onsubmit = (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();

        if (validator) {
            validator.validate().then((status) => {
                if (status === 'Valid') {
                    btnSubmit.setAttribute('data-kt-indicator', 'on');
                    btnSubmit.disabled = true;

                    const url = '<?= LINK_API ?>user/edit';
                    const data = new FormData(form);
                    const options = {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: data,
                        headers: {
                            Accept: 'application/json'
                        }
                    };

                    fetch(url, options)
                        .then(res => res.json)
                        .then(res => {
                            console.log(res);
                        })
                        .catch(err => console.error('Ocorreu um erro!', err))
                        .finally(() => {
                            btnSubmit.removeAttribute('data-kt-indicator');
                            btnSubmit.disabled = false;
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[Response I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3jeP.png)

[Payload of the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHBLS.png)

[Headers of the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKf3s.png)

But when I do the fetch instead of return the json dont return nothing, when I tried to access the file via GET method return me the json correct, anyone can help?

Comment: What response are you actually getting, when you check in the network panel of your browser dev tools? Is the request getting redirected, based on your code in `/api/check.php`, perhaps? (Btw., you have `/global/config.php` require the `/api/check.php` file, and `/api/check.php` requiring `/global/config.php` again. Only the use of `require_once` is saving you from an "endless loop" here.)

Comment: @CBroe
Firstly, thank you for your help! I just posted a printout of what was returned to me by the endpoint. As for the loop, I have no idea how I can make something more performant and well done as well.
**Edit:** As for the `check.php`, it is not affecting the code at all as I do a session check that will only run if the client is not logged in.

Comment: What does the payload that was sent, look like?

Comment: Just update the post with the printout of the payload.

Comment: And the response headers?

Comment: I just posted the print of the headers

Comment: It says `Content-Length: 264` in there, whereas the length of the actual JSON data you are sending, appears to be only 57 bytes. But I guess the excess could probably come from the gzip Content-Encoding.

Comment: I think that the size of the json does not imply the "bug" that is happening, in `/api/user/edit.php` when I import `/global/config.php` the json does not output but when I don't import `/global/config.php` the script runs and gives me an error in the const. If I remove sesison_start from `/global/config.php` the script runs normally and gives me an error in $_SESSION as expected. If you don't import `/global/config.php` and copy the constants to `/api/user/edit.php` and do session_start() it gives me the same "bug" (does not return anything)

Comment: Why are these files even trying to require each other in the first place?

Comment: As I am not using a framework, I centralized the global information to the project and by importing `/global/config.php`, it would soon work as a middleware. If it's not the right way to think I'm willing to change the code.

Comment: Your `/global/config.php` file is probably one you will be including _everywhere_, going by that name. And if that one already requires the `/api/check.php` at the end - then why does `/api/check.php` need to require `/global/config.php` again, in the "other direction"?

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help and corrections in advance. I still couldn't figure out why the "bug" was working that way.  :(

Comment: I just tried on Firefox and works perfectly fine...

Comment: The only reason this could behave differently in a different browser, is if that browser was sending a different request. Since you got sessions involved here, that is the first thing you should check - whether you get the session ID passed correctly, or if it changes between requests.

Comment: The sesison ID is the same but in `/api/user/edit.php` if i do this `session_start();
echo session_id();
exit;` still dont return the sesison ID just returns empty

Comment: You should not call session_start more than once (in fact, that should get you an error or a warning at least.)

Comment: Yea I know I call once but still gave me a "bug".

Comment: So I just copy the code from other file and just worked I dont know why but yea, it's resolved :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just resolve my own error/bug when I do the fetch POST request

**Wrong Code**

```js
fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json)
```

**Right Code**

```js
fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json())
```

So it's this code that makes the error happen.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).